# showing Insufficient permissions for the specified parent. when uploading files in telegram python mirror bot

Tags: python

@alenrafi Error.
HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&alt=json returned "Insufficient permissions for the specified parent.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientParentPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient permissions for the specified parent.'}]"